# Git post-receive hook distributed deployment

Tags: git

Let say we have LoadBalancer (LB), ProdWeb Replica A (PWA), ProdWeb Replica B (PWB). We currently have a git post-receive hook to run a git fetch from a bare repo on PWA. However LB uses round-robin and the Sandbox "production" remote is only pointed to proddomain.com which resolves to whichever server in next in queue (PWA or PWB). How is it possible to have one remote (production: git@proddomain.com:app.git) on a sandbox and trigger two post-receive hooks on both PWA and PWB. Ideally I would like to exclude any solution akin to samba share, rsync, virtual/network drives.